# IntelliSense alternative using SSMS 2012 in a contained database as a contained user?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, intellisense

According to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21837/are-there-disadvantages-to-contained-databases) about contained database disadvantages:

> If you connect to a contained database as a contained user, SSMS will
>   not fully support IntelliSense. You'll get basic underlining for
>   syntax errors, but no auto-complete lists or tooltips and all the fun
>   stuff. [I filed a bug about this issue, and it remains open.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/717063/ssms-intellisense-does-not-function-for-a-contained-user)

So is there any way to get IntelliSense-style functionality? Can anyone vouch for a product that will work in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think this is a problem with Management Studio, just that the user the tool has to act on behalf of does not have the permission to pull the metadata required to support IntelliSense. So I doubt other tools will fill the need. Your choices are:

1. Try other tools like SQL Prompt and SQL Complete
2. Use a server-level login with adequate DB privileges for development (vs. application runtime)
3. Live without IntelliSense

Hopefully they will [fix this problem at some point](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/717063/ssms-intellisense-does-not-function-for-a-contained-user). Even my Connect item incorrectly blames the UI when the problem is with the permissions (not) granted to the contained user.